# How to unit test code inside angular observable subscription

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am writing a unit test case for a code inside a subscription of observable as below. But this test fails. Can someone point me the mistake here.

****Component.ts****

```
this.myService.myData$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy)).subscribe(data=>{
 if (this.oldValue !== this.currentValue) {
  callThisFunction(data); 
}
})
```

****Unit test case*****
giving myServiceMock as provide useValue for myService in TestBed

```
 myServiceMock = {
       myValue: 'value'
       myData$: of([{a: 'name', b: 'age'}]) 
    }

it('test my data', done => {
        const myFuncStub = sinon.stub(component, 'callThisFunction');
        component.oldValue = 'x';
        component.myData$.subscribe(item => {
          expect(myFuncStub).to.have.been.called;
          done();
        });
      });
```